# Unable to populate values obtained from ajax call using PrimeFaces

Tags: ajax, jsf, xhtml, primefaces

Hi
                                     I have made an ajax call using primefaces [p:ajax]. The call to the listener was successful and it returned the required values. To update these properties in xhtml, I have checked the DOM source, to find out the exact ID of the column, using which the column or property would be updated. But, in this case the fields are not getting the values.

The code I used in this case is

```
        <p:dataTable id="table1" var="recepit" rowIndexVar="rowIndex"   value="#{ReceiptDetailsBean.iterativeList}" scrollable="true"  height="120px" styleClass="leftTable">

            <p:column style="background-color: #EFF2F9">
                <f:facet name="header">
                    <h:outputText value="SL NO" />
            </f:facet>
                    <h:outputText value="#{rowIndex+1}" />

            </p:column>

            <p:column >
                <f:facet name="header">
                    <h:outputText value="Buss." />
                </f:facet>

                        <h:selectOneMenu id="selectOneCb" value="#{ReceiptDetailsBean.bussCode}" >
                            <f:selectItem itemLabel="V_BUSS_CODE" itemValue=""/>
                            <f:selectItems value="#{ReceiptDetailsBean.rdetails}" var="model" itemLabel="#{model.buss}" itemValue="#{model.buss}"/>
                             <p:ajax update="mainForm:table1:#{rowIndex}:receiptCode, mainForm:table1:#{rowIndex}:referenceType"  actionListener="#{ReceiptDetailsBean.obtainReceiptDatabasedOnBussCode}" event="change"/>  
                        </h:selectOneMenu>

            </p:column>

            <p:column id="receiptCodeCol">
                <f:facet name="header">
                    <h:outputText value="Receipt Code" />
                </f:facet>

                        <h:inputText value="#{ReceiptDetailsBean.receiptCode}" id="receiptCode" style="font-family: verdana;font-size: 10px;width:80px;height:15px" />


            </p:column>

            <p:column id="receiptTypeCol">
                <f:facet name="header">
                    <h:outputText value="Ref Type" />
                </f:facet>

                        <h:inputText value="#{ReceiptDetailsBean.receiptType}" id="referenceType" style="font-family: verdana;font-size: 10px;width:80px;height:15px"/>


            </p:column>


        </p:dataTable>

                    </div>


        </p:tab>

        <p:tab title="Print">

        </p:tab>



</p:tabView>
</h:form>
```

The id from the DOM view source was table1:0:receiptCodeHotKey:receiptCode

What would be the problem for the data to not get populated in the field.

Answer (score 1):

I think the source of the problem is your usage of `h:form`. You don't need to put it around each single input element. Put *one* `h:form` around the datatable and then check again the generated ids.

Then it should be something like (example for first row with rowindex 0):

```
formId:table1:0:receiptCode
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply Matt.

I am supposed to show four dataTables with multiple ajax calls and submit buttons. When I removed the form for each particular element and maintained a single form for every dataTable as well as a single form for all the four dataTables. In both the cases, the listener call was not made.

Comment: In this case put only one `h:form` around all tables. In HTML it is not allowed to nest forms. Some browsers don't care but it is always a source of error

Comment: I am still facing the same problem. I mean I am able to make a listener call, but am not able to update the columns. I changed the code to accommodate a single form for all the dataTables and changed the update attribute in the ajax call. If I have given wrong reference in update attribute .... I would have got the warning in the log as " Component not found to be updated partially ". But I am not getting that warning in the log, which means I have referenced correctly. I am also using <p:tabView>, will that be a problem ? Please help me in this.

Comment: Did you try update="@form"? This will update the whole form, just as a test.

Comment: I did it just now. It says the component '@form' could not be found to update partially.

Comment: Ok, that's strange. I don't know if it is related to Primefaces but @form should always work if the component is embedded in a form. So you could also test it with `f:ajax`. The attributes are named a bit different: `<f:ajax render="@form" listener="yourListener"/>`

Comment: I have pasted the code I have changed, in the question. If possible, please look into the code and let me know if any errors.

Comment: The code looks fine. It is alway a bit tricky to update a dataTable from within the table. I often use a `h:panelGrid` around the table (and inside the form) and updated this. Give `f:ajax` a try.